# install windows 7 as dualboot

Tags: dual-boot

I have an hp pavilion g6 laptop that have ubuntu as operating system , and I had no other OS on it.
but now I need to install win7 with ubuntu.
and I cant do it.
can anybody help me with this

Comment: using gparted make a empty partition ntfs type and install windows 7 on it if your boot log is disturbed then make it a boot-repair